# What does an * (star) mean in front of a CSS declaration?

Tags: css

I'm using the Yahoo YUI libraries in a project. Can anyone help me understand the following CSS that I came across in the layout manager CSS:

I have been unable to figure out what the * (star) does to the declarations in the following CSS:

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-layout .yui-layout-unit div.yui-layout-bd {
border:1px solid #808080;
border-bottom:none;
border-top:none;
*border-bottom-width:0;
*border-top-width:0;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

This is a hack to apply styles only to older versions of IE 
the * declared styles will override the new style elements , that are unsuported by Od IE only.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack

Answer (score 3):

The star exploits a bug in version 7 and below of Internet Explorer and is used to make IE render your markup correctly. More information here: http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/63